# Phonegap: two pages are overlapping on Android

Tags: android, cordova

I am developing an Android/Phonegap app. Below is my code:

```
public class SharePointProjectActivity extends DroidGap {
  /* SharedPreferences are used so that any initial setup can be done, 
     * i.e operations that are done once in life-time of an application
     * such as coping of database file to required location, initial wait 
     * request page,etc.
  */
  private SharedPreferences myPreferences;
  private Boolean registration;
  private static final String PREFS_NAME = "Register";
  /** Called when the activity is first created. */
  @Override
  public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    myPreferences = PreferenceManager.getDefaultSharedPreferences(this);
    registration = myPreferences.getBoolean(PREFS_NAME, false);
    if (!registration) {
    //this code would load index1.html which would just display "Initialization is going on please wait"
      super.loadUrl("file:///android_asset/www/index1.html");
      try {
        //some code to copy the database files
      }
      catch (IOException e) {
        //some exception during the operation
      }
      //once the database file are copied i want to load the login page.Remember this would happen during installation only, successive runs (launch) would directly load the login page i.e index2.html
      super.loadUrl("file:///android_asset/www/index2.html");
      SharedPreferences.Editor editor = myPreferences.edit();
      editor.putBoolean(PREFS_NAME, true);
      editor.commit();
    } else {
      super.loadUrl("file:///android_asset/www/index.html");
    }
  }
```

Problem: During installation both pages are getting loaded one on top of the other, i.e. index2.html on top of index1.html.

Expected: During the copying process, index1.html should show and once that is done index1.html should fade away and index2.html should load.

Edited : I will be using two html file during the installation, the first file will just show an image asking user to wait while installation is going on and if everything goes fine then login page(second file) should be loaded. so far this is working but when i click on the back button control goes to the first page.
Thanks in advance,

Nanashi

Answer (score 1):

You could try working with a AsyncTask, if you'd use this, it would allow the user interaction with your app because you wouldn't be using the UI thread

```
public class LoadDataTask extends AsyncTask<Void, Void, Void> {
      protected void onPreExecute() {
            SharePointProjectActivity.this.super.loadUrl("file:///android_asset/www/index1.html");
      }

      protected void doInBackground(final Void... args) {
         ... do you db stuff ...
         return null;
      }

      @Override
      protected void onPostExecute(Void result) {
           SharePointProjectActivity.this.super.loadUrl("file:///android_asset/www/index2.html");
      }
   }
```

You can start an asynctask by doing

```
new LoadDataTast().execute();
```

Comment: i did as mentioned here but still not working. Thanks anyway for looking into it, if you have any other ideas please do suggest.